# Extracting values from an OrderedDictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

New to Python.  Have an OrderedDictionary that looks like this:

```
{name0 = OrderedDictionary([('name0', 'name'), ('year', '2000'), ('etc.', 'etc.')])}
```

the key, value pairs returns the outer `nest, k = name0, v = ([( ...)])`.

How can I access the tupples in the inner nest--> eg

```
('name0', 'name'), ('year', 2000'), ('etc.', 'etc.')
```

and keep the key handy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a given key's value in a nested ordered dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708586/find-a-given-keys-value-in-a-nested-ordered-dict-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {
    'name0': OrderedDict([
        ('name0', 'name'), 
        ('year', '2000'), 
        ('etc.', 'etc.')
    ])
}

res = []
for v in dictionary.values():
    for k, v in v.items():
        res.append((k, v))
```

Now `res` is `[('name0', 'name'), ('year', '2000'), ('etc.', 'etc.')]`.