# Print all paths to the keys and values in a nested OrderedDict with nested arrays

Tags: python, dictionary, path, nested, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to get the path from nested data structures with arrays and OderedDicts. The problem is that the function i found here: [Find a given key's value in a nested ordered dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708586/find-a-given-keys-value-in-a-nested-ordered-dict-python) will not work with arrays in it.

I've been trying this with Python version 3.7.3 on windows Environment.

This is how i would like it, but then with arrays:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mydict = OrderedDict ( {'a':
            OrderedDict ( {'b':
                OrderedDict ( [ ('chart_layout', '3'),
                 ('client_name', 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)'),
                 ('sort_order', 'asending'),
                 ('chart_type', 'pie'),
                 ('powerpoint_color', 'blue'),
                 ('crossbreak', 'Total')
                 ] ) } ) } )

def listRecursive (d, path = None):
    if not path: path = []
    for k, v in d.items ():
        if isinstance (v, OrderedDict):
            for path, found in listRecursive (v, path + [k] ):
                yield path, found
        if isinstance (v, str):
            yield path + [k], v

for path, found in listRecursive (mydict):
    print (path, found)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'chart_layout'] 3
['a', 'b', 'client_name'] Sport Parents (Regrouped)
['a', 'b', 'sort_order'] asending
['a', 'b', 'chart_type'] pie
['a', 'b', 'powerpoint_color'] blue
['a', 'b', 'crossbreak'] Total
```

This collection is not the actual one. Its more nested with arrays.

```
xml_order_dict = OrderedDict([('breakfast_menu',
                               OrderedDict([('food',
                                [OrderedDict([('name', 'Belgian Waffles'),
                                              ('price', '$5.95'),
                                              ('description',
                                               'Two of our famous Belgian Waffles '
                                               'with plenty of real maple syrup'),
                                              ('calories', '650')]),
                                 OrderedDict([('name',
                                           'Strawberry Belgian Waffles'),
                                              ('price', '$7.95'),
                                              ('description',
                                               'Light Belgian waffles covered with '
                                               'strawberries and whipped cream'),
                                              ('calories', '900')
                                             ])])]))])
def ListTags(d, key):
    for k, v in d.items ():
        if isinstance (v, OrderedDict):
            for found in listRecursive (v, key):
                yield found
        if k == key:
            yield v

for found in ListTags(xml_order_dict):
    print (found)
```

The expected results are:
Path to tag
the result of the tag

input:

```
for found in ListTags(xml_order_dict):
    print (found)
```

Output:
path = result

```
breakfast_menu['breakfast_menu']['food'][0]['name'] = Belgian Waffles
breakfast_menu['breakfast_menu']['food'][0]['price'] = $5.95
....
```

last one of the output:

```
breakfast_menu['breakfast_menu']['food'][1]['calories'] = 900
```

Excuse my English, I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
def list_recursive(mydict, path=()):
    if type(mydict) is list:
        for i, item in enumerate(mydict):
            list_recursive(item, path=(*path, i))
        return
    for k, v in mydict.items():
        if type(v) is str:
            print(*map(
                lambda x:f"['{x}']" if type(x) is str else f"[{x}]",
                (*path, k)
            ), '=', v, sep='')
        else:
            list_recursive(v, path=(*path, k))
```

If you are doing this to generate the code that can recreate the list, consider looking into [json formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks allot, i've been looking for this for two weeks, thanks!